# Find minimal simple graph, such that its automorphism group is isomorphic to the Klein four-group

Tags: graph-theory

Minimal meaning that $|V|+|E|$ is minimal (sum of number of vertices and edges). The graph is not necessarily connected.

How do I find this graph, and how do I prove minimality and unicity? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V_4\cong C_2\times C_2$, so $|V|=4, |E|=1$ has the right automorphism group, and there would be very few smaller graphs to check by hand.

---

A little more dignified than exhaustive search would be something like:

The automorphism group of a graph with $n$ vertices corresponds to a subgroup of $S_n$. From Lagrange's theorem we now know that we need $n!$ to be a multiple of $4$, so we're looking for a graph with at least $4$ vertices. $4$ or $5$ isolated points won't do (the automorphism group of that is far too large), but if we add a single edge we happen to get the right group. And now it is clear that we can't get through with any smaller $|V|+|E|$.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how you found the answer so fast. Is this something that one should know or can this be deduced? Say, for example, I wanted a graph for which $Aut(\Gamma) $ is isomorphic a the cyclic group $C_n$. How can this be found?

Comment: And also, am I correct in saying that a connected version of the graph I'm looking for does not exist?

Comment: @Zachary: It comes with experience. The way to think about the four-group I find most natural is $C_2\times C_2$, so I knew I was looking for a graph where there are two pairs of things that can either be flipped around or left alone, independently of each other. The smallest _thinkable_ way to do that would be to make each flippable pair just two vertices, and having an edge between one of the pairs and no edge between the other pair would nicely prevent them from interacting.

Comment: @Zachary: There are definitely connected graphs that have $V_4$ as their automorphism group. The smallest one I can think of right now would be a triangle with two single edges (ending in leaf nodes) sticking out from one of the vertices (giving 5 vertices, 5 edges -- this is the same as the disconnected example above, with an additional vertex that connects to everything) but I'm far from sure it is actually minimal.